# Laravel hasManyThrough in depth

Tags: laravel, has-many-through, relationships

I have been looking at documentation regarding the hasManyThrough relationship in Laravel, and fro some reason I am struggling with it as the documentation makes it look simple (maybe I am overthinking it)....

I have three Models tables at the moment:

```
-User (extends authenticatable)
    id, 
    name, 
    surname, 
    email, 
    password.

-Order
    id, 
    user_id, 
    name, 
    unit, 
    qty

-Product (i need to add a qty table to show how many is ordered).
    id, 
    order_id, 
    name, 
    unit, 
    description, 
    family
```

My Products model is used by Admin to CRUD products.

Please can someone explain to me how I will be able to display to admin which user made an order, and what does the order consist of. 
I also want to display to the user a 'order history'..

Please will anyone be able to assist..

UPDATE

```
-order_product
  id,
  order_id,
  product_id
  quantity
```

product controller:

```
  public function orders()
    {
       return $this->belongsToMany('App\Order')->withPivot('quantity');
    }
```

order controller:

```
  public function products()
    {
       return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product')->withPivot('quantity');
    }
```

Comment: Mention fields of tables

Comment: User field:
id, name, surname, email, password.

Order field:
id, user_id, name, unit, qty

Product fields:
id, order_id, name, unit, description, family

Comment: Its Many to many relationship. Not has many through. and  your quantity table should named as order_product that should contains fields like id, product_id, order_id, qty https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Comment: So I will have a pivot table called 'order_product', I thought so initially but after I started I wondered how will it track what user made the order if it does not have a user_id column?

Comment: User id column is there in you product table. You can group all order by user_id.

Comment: it makes sense. I will give it a try and see if I come right. If I want to pull all orders in the admin view? as well as how will I show the user his order in the view. how will the forloop look like for these two instances?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need create one more table like order_details

```
-User (extends authenticatable)
    id, 
    name, 
    surname, 
    email, 
    password.

-Order
    id, 
    user_id, 
    name, 
    unit, 
    qty

-Product (i need to add a qty table to show how many is ordered).
    id, 
    name, 
    unit, 
    description, 
    family
-Order_detail(Store product_id, order_id (You can put qty to this table))
    id,
    order_id,
    product_id
```

Answer (score 0):

It is many to many to relationship show you'll have to create one another pivot table named
**order_product** with fields

-id

-order_id

-product_id

-quantity

and in your **Order table Model** define relationship as

```
public function products()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product')->withPivot('quantity');
}
```

and in your **Product table Model** define relationship as

```
public function orders()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany('App\Order')->withPivot('quantity');
}
```

to Retrieve data

```
$order= App\Order::find(1);

@foreach ($order->products as $product)
    echo $product->pivot->quantity."<br>";
@endforeach
```

Comment: I am getting very confused now. I need to search a order by the user_id, the user_id must have all the orders that user ever made, if I click on one of the orders, a list of the products ordered must appear?

Comment: post a code in question so, can get a clear idea about what you have done till now

Comment: Sorry I am new with stack overflow and I can't seem to get my code in the correct format

Comment: click on edit below question and mention the new code at end

Comment: how you fetch data? Mention the output

Comment: I see my problem is pulling the product information from the product controller, and submitting it to the pivot table

Comment: where must my submit button save to?

Comment: I am trying to post these data to a table and then fetch it again.

Comment: no not yet. I am still not able to achieve what I set out to do